# How to ignore space after comma when reading in multiple items in java

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I want to ask a user for multiple names, separated by commas. I want to then break down the names individually. I am reading the input into a string which then I split by the ','. However, the program is not functioning properly whenever the user enters a space after the comma, but before the next name. See below.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class getInput {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Please enter names seperated by a ',':> ");
        String testInput = sc.nextLine();
        String[] names = testInput.split(",");
        for (String name : names) {
            String[] partialName = name.split(" ");
            if (partialName[0].equals(" ")){
                if (partialName.length == 4) {
                    System.out.println("Should be a space: " + partialName[0]);
                    System.out.println("First Name: " + partialName[1]);
                    System.out.println("Middle Name: " + partialName[2]);
                    System.out.println("Last Name: " + partialName[3]);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("First Name: " + partialName[1]);
                    System.out.println("Last Name: " + partialName[2]);
                }
            }
            else {
                if (partialName.length == 3) {
                    System.out.println("First Name: " + partialName[0]);
                    System.out.println("Middle Name: " + partialName[1]);
                    System.out.println("Last Name: " + partialName[2]);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("First Name: " + partialName[0]);
                    System.out.println("Last Name: " + partialName[1]);
                }
            }
        }

        sc.close();
    }
}
```

For Example:

```
Please enter names seperated by a ',':> Joe Smith, Jack Sparrow Doe,Steve Parker
First Name: Joe
Last Name: Smith
First Name: 
Last Name: Jack
First Name: Steve
Last Name: Parker
```

It seems to me like it is reading the space after the first comma at the first name of that person. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

trim() removes whitespace at the beginning and at the end.

```
String[] names = testInput.split(",");
    for (String name : names) {
        String[] partialName = name.trim().split(" ");
```

Comment: No problem, can you mark my answer as solution for your question?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ",\s*" as a regex so the regex-engine uses a comma and space as a delimiter.

Comment: would that be inside the useDelimiter() function attached to the scanner object?

Comment: in your split-method

Comment: Thanks for your help! Eclipse is telling me that is an Invalid escape sequence. I am a bit new to Java (if it isn't obvious haha). If I got that to work, would it handle situations where the user did not include a space after the comma? I need something that can handle both situations.

Comment: Stackoverflow swollowed my second \ its `",\\s*"`